# Plot basic graphs (inequality)

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I am beginner (and it is my fourth article here) and I am struggling with plotting some basic graphs. I found here some similar articles, but it did not help me. :( 
I want to plot graph, where is: `y>= (1/x) (blue) and x<=0 (red)`.
I thank you in advance for any help.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{only axis on top/.style={axis on top=false, after end axis/.code={ \pgfplotsset{axis line style=opaque, ticklabel style=opaque, tick style=opaque, grid=none}\pgfplotsdrawaxis}}}
\newcommand{\drawge}{-- (rel axis cs:5,0) -- (rel axis cs:5,5) -- (rel axis cs:0,5) \closedcycle}
\newcommand{\drawle}{-- (rel axis cs:5,5) -- (rel axis cs:5,0) -- (rel axis cs:0,0) \closedcycle}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htpb] 
        \centering 
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
            \begin{axis}[only axis on top,
            axis line style=very thick, 
            axis x line=middle, 
            axis y line=middle, 
            ymin=-3,ymax=5.99,xmin=-3,xmax=5.99, 
            xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,grid=major 
            ] 
            \addplot [draw=none, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=0.01:6]
            {1/x} \drawge;
            \addplot[very thick, domain=0.01:6,-] {1/x}; 
            \addplot [draw=none, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red!40, domain=-3:0]
            {-3:0} \drawge;
            \end{axis} 
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    %   \caption{Prípad 1} 
    \end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik can I ask, how did you change it, please?

Comment: You mean to format as code? You just select the code and click the `{}` button, like here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGnsG.png Any line that begins with four spaces is formatted as code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You make your own life a bit complicated by running all these things in the beginning. Assuming you will use them somewhere, I left them in, and propose

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{only axis on top/.style={axis on top=false, after end axis/.code={ \pgfplotsset{axis line style=opaque, ticklabel style=opaque, tick style=opaque, grid=none}\pgfplotsdrawaxis}}}
\newcommand{\drawge}{-- (rel axis cs:5,0) -- (rel axis cs:5,5) -- (rel axis cs:0,5) \closedcycle}
\newcommand{\drawle}{-- (rel axis cs:5,5) -- (rel axis cs:5,0) -- (rel axis cs:0,0) \closedcycle}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htpb] 
        \centering 
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
            \begin{axis}[only axis on top,
            axis line style=very thick, 
            axis x line=middle, 
            axis y line=middle, 
            ymin=-3,ymax=5.99,xmin=-3,xmax=5.99, 
            xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,grid=major,samples=101 
            ] 
            \addplot [draw=none, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=0.01:6]
            {1/x} \drawge;
            \addplot[very thick, domain=0.01:6,-] {1/x};
            \addplot[draw=none,name path=top] {6};
            \addplot[draw=none,name path=bottom] {-6};
            \addplot [pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red!40] fill between [of=top and bottom,soft  clip={domain=-3:0}];
            \end{axis} 
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    %   \caption{Prípad 1} 
    \end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

As for additional request.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{only axis on top/.style={axis on top=false, after end axis/.code={ \pgfplotsset{axis line style=opaque, ticklabel style=opaque, tick style=opaque, grid=none}\pgfplotsdrawaxis}}}
\newcommand{\drawge}{-- (rel axis cs:5,0) -- (rel axis cs:5,5) -- (rel axis cs:0,5) \closedcycle}
\newcommand{\drawle}{-- (rel axis cs:5,5) -- (rel axis cs:5,0) -- (rel axis cs:0,0) \closedcycle}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htpb] 
        \centering 
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
            \begin{axis}[only axis on top,
            axis line style=very thick, 
            axis x line=middle, 
            axis y line=middle, 
            ymin=-3,ymax=5.99,xmin=-3,xmax=5.99, 
            xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,grid=major,samples=101 
            ] 
%             \addplot [draw=none, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=0.01:6]
%             {1/x};
            \addplot[name path=A,very thick, domain=0.01:6,-] {1/x};
            \addplot[draw=none,name path=top, domain=-3:6] {6};
            \addplot[draw=none,name path=bottom] {-6};
            \addplot [pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red!40] fill between [of=top and bottom,soft  clip={domain=-3:0}];
            \addplot [pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue!40] fill
            between [of=top and A,soft  clip={domain=0:6}];
            \end{axis} 
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    %   \caption{Prípad 1} 
    \end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. 
Can I ask, how should I change it, if I want to have function x<=0 red? Because part for y>0 is violet. :( Maybe I have some mistake in functon y>= (1/x) for x>0?

Is there some possibility to do it easier?

Comment: @Euler I added something...